# MSMQ Send multicast message to remote server

Tags: .net, msmq, messaging, multicast

We have MSMQ on `ServerA` & `ServerB`, along with two services on each.

We want both of the services to send message to the multicast queues on `ServerA` (many queues that have the same multicast address, so when one message is sent it appears in all queues).

When the service on `ServerA` sends a multicast message it appears on all queues on that server and it works just fine. But, when `ServerB` sends a multicast message it's only appearing on `ServerB` (where we don't have queues) and not on `ServerA`.

The address we're using for multicast is 224.0.255.1:80.

How can we send a message from a service located on `ServerB` to appear in all multicast queues on `ServerA`?

(Permissions are all allowed to both anonymous & everyone, for debugging purposes just to move this issue out of the picture)

Comment: I don't understand this: "when ServerB sends a multicast message it's only appearing on ServerB (where we don't have queues)" How can a message appear where there are no queues? What are you actually seeing?

Comment: If you send a multicast message on a msmq server that has no matching address in a queue it automatically gets placed in the auto-created "Outgoing Queues", with the name of the multicast address. So, yes, it's a queue, but it's not our queue.

Comment: Just to add - the queue does get created but message is nowhere to be found (not in outgoing, journal, dead-letter or other system queue)

Comment: The outgoing queue is normal. That's how MSMQ sends messages to non-local queues. Multicast messaging depends on your network not blocking the traffic. You don't mention how ServerA and ServerB are physically separated. Sniffing network traffic is a good start to ensure ServerA actually sees multicast messages from ServerB. Are there any errors in the event logs? What is the status of the outgoing queue? Are messages over 64kb in size?